# sum of two consecutive squares that add up to a square

Tags: number-theory

Find all integer $x$ s.t. there is an integer $r$.

$x^2+(x+1)^2=r^2$

What if $x$ is a square?

All of my attempts lead to dead ends.

Comment: You you know how to solve Pell's equation? In the general case ($x$ square or note) it reduces to that, but if you don't know how to solve that...

Comment: Please show me how it reduces to a Pell equation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry, I was too hasty in posting my answer.

Comment: $2x^2+2x+1=r^2$ iff $4x^2+4x+2=2r^2$ iff $(2x+1)^2+1=2r^2$. So we are looking at Pellian $z^2-2r^2=-1$. Now general solution can be written down, or a recurrence.

Comment: No need to apologize, @PrimeRibeyeDeal. We've all done it.

Answer (score 5):

If you know how to solve Pell's equation, then you are trying to solve:

$$(2x+1)^2-2r^2 = -1$$ which is a common variant of Pell's equation.

Comment: My answer obviously doesn't answer the question about when $x$ is a square, which is harder...

Comment: Could you recommend me a good refference to solving Pell equations?

Comment: Not other than saying, "google Pell's equation." In this case, it's just: $2x+1+r\sqrt 2 = (1+\sqrt 2)^{2k+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

About the case where $x$ is square:

Following the standard solution to Pell's equation, the solution to this problem is given by the following recurrences: $$y_n = 2x_n + 1$$ $$y_0 = 1, y_1=7, y_{n+2}=6y_{n+1}-y_n$$ $$r_0 = 1,r_1=5, r_{n+2}=6r_{n+1}-r_n$$

So the problem is equivalent to finding out when $y_n-1$ is equal to twice a square.  $n=0$ is probably the only solution.  I suspect that this is a moderately hard but solvable problem—in principle it should be approximately as hard as finding all square Fibonacci numbers, which is very tricky to do with elementary methods.

Comment: For those interested, there is a closed form:
$$
y_n=\frac{1+\sqrt2}2(3+2\sqrt2)^n+\frac{1-\sqrt2}2(3-2\sqrt2)^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a series of reductions you may find helpful:

Consider the more general problem of finding triplets of integers $(a,b,c)$ such that

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

It's know that if $a = m^2-n^2$and $b=2mn$ that in general

$$(m^2-n^2)^2 + (2mn)^2 = m^4+ 2m^2n^2 + n^4= (m^2+n^2)^2$$

Thus for every pair of integers $m,n$ we can generate a triple $a,b,c$ that satisfies this equation.

Now we are concerned with solutions such that $2mn = m^2-n^2 + 1$

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that there is a relationship with solutions of Pell's equation, but it must still be written more clearly and in a more general way.

Solutions of the equation: $$X^2+(X\pm{a})^2=Y^2$$

Defined solutions of Pell's equation: $$p^2-2s^2=\pm{a}$$

And the solutions are of the form:      $$X=2s(s+p)$$      $$Y=2s(s+p)+p^2$$
These numbers can be different characters.   I almost forgot.

If we know what the solution of Pell's equation $$p^2-2s^2=a$$    $$s_{2}=2p+3s$$    $$p_{2}=3p+4s$$