# Finding integer solutions to $n^2 = 2d^2 - 2d + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples, pell-type-equations

I'm trying to find the smallest integer solution to

$$n^2 = 2d^2 - 2d + 1$$

Additional constraints: $$d > 10^{12}, n > 0$$

I wrote a computer program to bruteforce it, but that is too slow.

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110142820/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68414.html) says that I can consider the equation modulo some prime to find whether it has solutions, but I already know that it *has* a solution, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: If you set $d=c+1$, your equation becomes $n^2=c^2+(c+1)^2$, which is analyzed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/864690/73324).

Comment: With @vadim123s factorization, you should see a solution. I am surprised your brute force did not give you that one though.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424587/when-is-5n214n1-a-perfect-square/2424845#2424845

Comment: You have $n^2=(d-1)^2+d^2$ so apply Phytagorean triples.

Answer (score 4):

It's $$n^2=d^2+(d-1)^2$$ and we got Pythagorean triples because we can assume that $d-1>0$,

otherwise it's or obvious or the same.

Since $gcd(d,d-1)=1$, we have two cases.

1. $d=2mn$ and $d-1=m^2-n^2$, where $gcd(m,n)=1$, $m>n$ and $mn$ is even;
2. $d=m^2-n^2$ and $d-1=2mn$.

We got two Pell's equations:
$$(m+n)^2=1+2m^2$$ and $$(m-n)^2=1+2n^2.$$
They are $y^2=1+2x^2$ with a minimal solution $(2,3)$ and from here we can get all solutions.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$n^2=2d^2+2d-1\implies d^2+(d-1)^2=n^2$$

which can translate to a Pythagorean triple
$\qquad A^2+B^2=C^2=n^2\quad\text{where }\quad B=A\pm1$

The $(m,k)$ values for to generate these triples are adjacent [Pell numbers](https://oeis.org/A000129) which can be generated by a simple derivation of Euclid's formula $ \quad A=m^2-k^2,\quad B=2mk,\quad C=m^2+k^2\quad$ where each m-value generated is the k-value for the next iteration of the formula

\begin{equation}\quad m=k+\sqrt{2k^2+(-1)^k}\end{equation}
Only $19$ can be generated with $15$-digit precision but it is simple and quick in a spreadsheet. It looks like the answer you seek, where $d>10^{12}$ is number $16$ in the list below.

\begin{equation}
0)\quad F(m,k)=(d,(d\pm1),n)\\
1)\quad  F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\
2)\quad  F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
3)\quad  F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\
4)\quad  F(29,12)=(697,696,985)\\
5)\quad  F(70,29)=(4059,4060,5741)\\
6)\quad  F(169,70)=(23661,23660,33461)\\
7)\quad  F(408,169)=(137903,137904,195025)\\
8)\quad  F(985,408)=(803761,803760,1136689)\\
9)\quad  F(2378,985)=(4684659,4684660,6625109)\\
10)\quad  F(5741,2378)=(27304197,27304196,38613965)\\
11)\quad  F(13860,5741)=(159140519,159140520,225058681)\\
12)\quad  F(33461,13860)=(927538921,927538920,1311738121)\\
13)\quad  F(80782,33461)=(5406093003,5406093004,7645370045)\\
14)\quad  F(195025,80782)=(31509019101,31509019100,44560482149)\\
15)\quad  F(470832,195025)=(183648021599,183648021600,259717522849)\\
16)\quad  F(1136689,470832)=(1070379110497,1070379110496,1513744654945)\\
17)\quad  F(2744210,1136689)=(6238626641379,6238626641380,8822750406821)\\
18)\quad  F(6625109,2744210)=(36361380737781,36361380737780,51422757785981)\\
19)\quad  F(15994428,6625109)=(211929657785303,211929657785304,299713796309065)\\
\end{equation}

Answer (score -2):

Found a solution.

Valid values of d have a ratio of approx 5.82842712474619 between them. (Is this ratio significant in some way? Damned if I know.)

In other words, if you know that 1235216565974041 is a valid value, then you can guess that 7199369738058942 is a valid value, which is only 2 away from 7199369738058940, which is correct.

This makes the problem bruteforceable, and solves my problem.